# How to ssh into a specific computer on server?

Tags: ssh

When ssh into a collection of computers on my University server I get assigned a particular machine and the machine changes every time (I assume based on how much each is being used). In other words when I type,

```
ssh username@servername
```

I get

```
username@nws##:~$
```

where ## is some number between 1-25. However, I would like to create processes on several machines and would rather select which computer I am ssh into. Is there a way for me to choose which machine I want to use?

Comment: Ask your admin. Anyhow, SO isn't the right place for this kind of question anyway, since it has nothing to do with programming but is rather a regular software use problem. superuser.com may be a better place.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the specific hostname (or more likely, the specific IP address) of the server you want to access, and then

```
ssh username@specifichostname
```

It is possible that the individual machines are not directly accessible from wherever you are `ssh`'ing from, in which case, you might have to

```
ssh username@servername
ssh username@specifichostname
```